# Date Formatter and ParseException - migration from Java to C#

Tags: c#, java

This is the updated version of my C# class where I am getting the message:

> Unreachable code detected : **DateTime.Now.Ticks;**

Everything else seems to be ok. Where is my mistake?

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace domain
{
    public class Request : Unique
    {
        private DateTime dateBooked_Renamed;

        private DateTime dateSignedIn ;

        private DateTime dateSignedOut ;

        private bool arrived_Renamed = false;

        private bool paid_Renamed = false;

        private Hotel hotel_Renamed;

        private Employee employee_Renamed;

        private int numberOfNights;

        public Request(Hotel hotel, Employee employee, string dateBooked, string dateArrived, int numberOfNights)
            : base()
        {
            this.hotel_Renamed = hotel;
            this.employee_Renamed = employee;
            this.numberOfNights = numberOfNights;
            try
            {
                DateTime.ParseExact(dateBooked, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                this.dateBooked_Renamed = DateTime.ParseExact(dateBooked, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                this.dateSignedIn = DateTime.ParseExact(dateArrived, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }

        public virtual bool checkout(double money, string date)
        {
            try
            {
                dateCheckedOut = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
            }
            if (money >= price())
            {
                paid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                paid = false;
            }
            return paid_Renamed;
        }

        public virtual int days()
        {
            long tNow = dateSignedOut != null ? dateSignedOut.Ticks : DateTime.Now.Ticks; 
            long tThen = arrived ? dateArrived.Ticks : tNow;
            long diff = tNow - tThen;

            long secondInMillis = 1000;
            long minuteInMillis = secondInMillis * 60;
            long hourInMillis = minuteInMillis * 60;
            long dayInMillis = hourInMillis * 24;
            long yearInMillis = dayInMillis * 365;

            diff = diff % yearInMillis;
            long elapsedDays = diff / dayInMillis;

            return (int)elapsedDays;
        }

        public virtual Hotel hotel
        {
            get
            {
                return hotel_Renamed;
            }
            set
            {
                this.hotel_Renamed = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual DateTime dateArrived
        {
            get
            {
                return dateSignedIn;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dateSignedIn = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual DateTime dateBooked
        {
            get
            {
                return dateBooked_Renamed;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dateBooked_Renamed = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual DateTime dateCheckedOut
        {
            get
            {
                return dateSignedOut;
            }
            set
            {
                this.dateSignedOut = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual Employee employee
        {
            get
            {
                return employee_Renamed;
            }
            set
            {
                this.employee_Renamed = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool arrived
        {
            get
            {
                return arrived_Renamed;
            }
            set
            {
                this.arrived_Renamed = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual bool paid
        {
            get
            {
                return paid_Renamed;
            }
            set
            {
                this.paid_Renamed = value;
            }
        }

        public virtual double price()
        {
            // The total cost of the stay...

            double price = days() * employee_Renamed.type.price;
            if (hotel_Renamed.premium)
            {
                return price - (0.2 * price);
            }
            else
            {
                return price;
            }
        }



        public virtual bool hasArrivalDate(string date)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                Console.WriteLine("Comparing " + d + " with " + dateSignedIn + " = " + dateSignedIn.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Equals(d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")));
                return dateSignedIn.ToString().Equals(d.ToString());
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what beast are you currently battling sir knight of java? (whats not working)

Comment: Please be more precise about your problem.  Create a toy example (fewer than 20 lines of code) that fails in the same way.  Then, state what your toy example does, and what you want it to do (e.g., "I expected it to output `foo bar bash`, but it threw a an error: `ParseException on Line X`")

Comment: By defining date format and by getting the previous date and the current date I tried to calculate the amount of time but as I said above it seems that .Net does not have the same command for DateFormat, getTimeZone, SimpleDateFormat and ParseException

Ps: As an example you can see line 4 and 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your date string in standard form, you can use `DateTime.Parse(date)`
If not, you can use `DateTime.ParseExact(date,"your custom format",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

As a sample from your code

```
public virtual bool hasArrivalDate(string date)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(date,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                Console.WriteLine("Comparing " + d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " with " + dateSignedIn.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + " = " + dateSignedIn.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy").Equals(d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")));
                return dateSignedIn.ToString().Equals(d.ToString());
            }
            catch (FormatException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Console.Write(e.StackTrace);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

So, it's no need instance of DateFormat

Comment: @NikolayDyankov See my edited post. And use `FormatException` for replace `ParseException`

Comment: Thanks it seems that part of the problem is solved but I still have problem with the dateFormatter:

      this.dateBooked_Renamed = dateFormatter.parse(dateBooked);

      this.dateSignedIn = dateFormatter.parse(dateArrived);

Comment: @NikolayDyankov. Do the same to them, like `DateTime.ParseExact(dateBooked,"dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. Or, what kind of problem is it?

Comment: The problems are two the first one is CultureInfo -does not exist in the current context

Comment: The second one is in the "no implicit conversion between System.DateTime and long" and in particullary in tNow: long tNow = dateSignedOut != null ? dateSignedOut : DateTime.Now.time;
            long tThen = arrived_Renamed ? dateArrived : tNow;
            long diff = tNow - tThen;

Comment: use this namespace `System.Globalization`

Comment: The problem with the CultureInfo is solved! Thank you! Can you just help me to solve the second one which is above

Comment: `DateTime` instance has `Ticks` property like `DateTime.Now.Ticks`. it suppose to be what you need

Comment: long tNow = dateSignedOut != null ? dateSignedOut.getTime()
                : new Date().getTime();
            long tThen = arrived ? getDateArrived().getTime() : tNow;

I reaaly don't know how to represent it into C# code? can u just help me with the transformation

Comment: It seems the C# implementation of my Java code was not correct and was confusing.

Comment: @NikolayDyankov. This for your code: `long tNow = dateSignedOut != null ? dateSignedOut.Ticks : DateTime.Now.Ticks; long tThen = arrived ? dateArrived.Ticks : tNow;`

Comment: I replace the code that u gave me but if you look at my first post, where I updated the code I am getting unreachable code detected for DateTime.Now.Ticks;

Comment: @NikolayDyankov In this part `dateSignedOut != null`. C# have no null value of instance of DateTime, So, the result will always true

Comment: Thank you for spotting the wrong part of the code. The way how I tried to "repair" the code was: `long tNow = dateSignedOut != DateTime? dateSignedOut.Ticks : DateTime.Now.Ticks; `, but an error type used like a variable appear. Do you have any idea how to solve the problem.

PS: I really want to apologize for the bad format of my questions. In the other post will change it.

Comment: Although `dateSignedOut` has been set, it will always have value as `DateTime.MaxValue`. So, it better to assign long `tNow = dateSignedOut.Ticks` and set initial value of `dateSignedOut` as `private DateTime dateSignedOut = DateTime.Now`.

Comment: I just amended the class and assign : 
` private DateTime dateSignedOut = DateTime.Now;` and 
`long tNow = dateSignedOut.Ticks;` , but in this case do you think that long tThen and  long diff will work properly or they need to be amended?

Comment: @NikolayDyankov. Yes, but actually you can simplify your `days()` function by `return dateSignedOut.Subtract(dateArrived).Days;`

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the dateSignedOut variable is a `DateTime`, which can never be null.

Therefore, in this line:

```
long tNow = dateSignedOut != null ? dateSignedOut.Ticks : DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

dateSignedOut will never be null, and therefore the "else" part of your statement will never be reached.

If you want dateSignedOut to be nullable, make it a `Nullable<DateTime>` (or `DateTime?`).

As an aside, please format your questions so that they are more readable.  This one is in real danger of being closed.  Better questions will lead to better answers.

**Update based on comment**

You should probably try to learn a little more about how properties are generally written in C#, but that's beyond the scope of this question.  To use the code you already have:

```
private DateTime? dateSignedOut;  // Notice the ? to make it Nullable
long tNow = dateSignedOut.HasValue ? dateSignedOut.Ticks : DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

Take a look at some [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx), or Google Nullable types.

Comment: Hi @Wonko the Sane,

1st I want to apologize for the bad formating.
2nd Initially my JAVA code was: 
`long tNow = dateSignedOut != null ? dateSignedOut.getTime()
    : new Date().getTime();`

and now I am very confused and do not know how to transfer it into proper C# code. May I ask you by any chance if you have time to write this line for me ?

Regards Nikolay Dyankov

Comment: I shouldn't, but seeing how you're new here, you get a pass (once).  See my updated answer.  If this helps you, mark it as the answer (the little checkmark next to the answer), and optionally vote it up (the little up arrow above the score).  This is general SO ettiquette (and you'll get points, too).